# is my phone najis

Tags: salat

i take my phone to the bathroom and place it on the counter and sometimes i touch it when i’m in the bathroom but i can’t remember if i touched it with najis hands or not but i do not see any sort of sign of impurity on my phone, i sometimes pray with this phone in my pocket or with this phone in front of me if i forget the last part of prayer and my head touches it is my phone najis and my prayers invalid

Comment: Why do you take your phone to the bathroom?

Comment: because sometimes someone calls or texts me

Comment: couldn’t you just call them back?

Comment: well sometimes if it’s my mom i wouldn’t want to miss it

Comment: but it doesn’t take that long to use the bathroom?

Comment: also it’s just a habit i have and i’m trying to stop doing it

Comment: You shouldn't speak in a toilet as this at least is makruh. A person who wants to speak with you would call you again, else you still can call back it is better to respect Allah than to respect others.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you in the most simplest way I can.

First of all, whenever you take your cell phone to the bathroom I'm sure you do not touch it with your hand right after you have cleaned your waste with the very same hands.

Secondly, just taking anything with you in the bathroom doesn't make it impure. If that was true then we would be instructed to also change our clothes and scrub ourselves thoroughly every time we come out of the bathroom.

Comment: i’m unsure because today i used the bathroom and after using water i dry with tissue so when i dried it my hand touched the urine but when i touched my phone there was no wetness or trace of urine

Comment: How did your hand touch the urine? I'm sorry don't understand that..